# About the sum of sines of two angles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

Suppose that $0\le \alpha\le \pi/2$ and $0\le \beta\le \pi/2$ such that
$\alpha+\beta\ge \pi/2$. Can we prove that $\sin(\alpha)+\sin(\beta)\ge 1$?

Comment: This is true for the function $\frac{2}{\pi}x$, which is smaller than $\sin(x)$ on the interval in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite it as 
$$\sin(\alpha)+\sin(\beta)= 2 \sin\left( \frac{\alpha + \beta}{2} \right) \cos\left( \frac{\alpha - \beta}{2} \right)$$
Note that $\frac\pi2 \leq\alpha+\beta\leq\pi$ so that $\sin\left( \frac{\alpha + \beta}{2} \right)\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$, and $-\frac\pi2\leq\alpha-\beta\leq\frac\pi2$ so that $\cos\left( \frac{\alpha - \beta}{2}\right)\geq \frac1{\sqrt2}$. Putting this together, we have
$$\sin(\alpha)+\sin(\beta)= 2 \sin\left( \frac{\alpha + \beta}{2} \right) \cos\left( \frac{\alpha - \beta}{2} \right)\geq2\cdot\frac1{\sqrt2}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt2}=1$$

Comment: @user35616 It should have been $-\pi/2\le\alpha-\beta\le\pi/2$.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited it. Luckily that doesn't change anything :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin\alpha+\sin\beta\ge \sin(\pi/2-\beta)+\sin\beta=\cos\beta+\sin\beta=\sqrt{\cos^2\beta+\sin^2\beta+2\cos\beta\sin\beta}\ge\sqrt 1=1$$

> $0\le\pi/2-\beta\le\alpha\le\pi/2\implies\sin(\pi-\beta)\le\sin\alpha\\0\le\beta\le\pi/2\implies 0\le\cos\beta\land0\le\sin\beta$